# Making an AI - How to make path finding?

Tags: lua, roblox

Hey, I am making an AI on ROBLOX and I can't seem to figure out where to start for path finding, the most common AI feature. Can anyone help?

P.S. I don't know any raycasting, so I can't use that as my option.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

Comment: Then LEARN about raycasting. If you don't plan to put effort in it, just don't even start.

Comment: @Dmitiri: It needs to be for Roblox. @Lagerbaer: How can I start THAT then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested, you'll want to take a look at the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star).  It's the workhouse of pathfinding.  If you don't think you can do that, try something simpler.  There are many techniques out there, including breadcrumb trails for pursuing AI characters, for example.  You could even apply a barebones (1,0,0) vector for moving right, (-1,0,0) vector for moving left, and so on at specific intervals while your game is running.  Just get something working first.  In any case, you'll probably encounter [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28computer_science%29) at one point or another while adding pathfinding, so read up on the subject.

Comment: By the way, isn't it funny that on a thread that was also about path finding have the **EXACT** same text in a reply?

Comment: That IS odd, but I can assure you that I don't copy-paste answers and if I do copy something, I cite (if that's what you meant).

Answer (score 0):

Roblox have [released](http://blog.roblox.com/2014/07/make-smarter-npcs-using-new-pathfinding-script-functions/) a [PathfindingService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/PathfindingService) which makes [pathfinding](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Pathfinding) quite easy :)